# How to change TAB the default value column separator in Memcached mysql cluster 7.2.2 ?

Tags: mysql, memcached

I am using memcached with mysql cluster 7.2.2. I had configured one table in container with one column as key column and remaining columns as value column.By default tab is separator for value columns. So i am confused if tab comes in data of value column then is it consider as column or data ? Can set other separater rather than tabs for value column separater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no support at present either for changing the separator, or for escaping an inline tab character. (So far the use cases have been simple ones, with a series of numeric columns at the start of the response and one text column at the end).